# How can I activate the CSS code in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, opencart

I am using OpenCart 3.0.3.8. The eshop is https://morrisdirect.co.uk
At the end of the stylesheet.css file, I added the following CSS code:

```
@media all and (min-width: 900px) {
    .container-two-columns {
    }
    .columns-two-columns {
       column-count: 2;
       column-gap: 0.3em;
    }
}
```

I am calling this CSS code from the homepage (and some more pages) to put the (below the slider) pictures next to each other. It is running perfectly in desktop Firefox and Opera, but it is not running in Chrome.

Can you help me please? :)

[image: The result]

Comment: You need to set the `<a>` tags to `display: block` for the column property to work: `.columns-two-columns > a { display: block; }` Add that rule after your current `.columns-two-columns` rule.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, disinfor.
I am sorry, but I don't have any CSS knowledge.
I tried to add the following code (as I understood from your answer), but it is not worked: 

`@media all and (min-width: 900px) > a { display: block; }{
  .container-two-columns {
  }
  .columns-two-columns  {
   column-count: 2;        
  column-gap: 0.3em;
  }
}`

Would it be possible to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the `<a>` elements block elements for this to work:

```
@media all and (min-width: 900px) {
    .columns-two-columns {
       column-count: 2;
       column-gap: 0.3em;
    }
    .columns-two-columns > a {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

You don't need the:

```
.container-two-columns {
    }
```

Since it's not doing anything.

Comment: Hey disinfor.
With your suggestions, I solve the issue.
Thank you very much for your help
Konstantinos

Comment: @Konstantinos great! You can upvote and accept this answer if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This can be one way as per your code:

```
@media all and (min-width: 900px) {
.container-two-columns {
}
.columns-two-columns {
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 0.3em;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

}

[image: Display Added]